# Count words or characters in a Notion table view

Tags: formulas, notion

In a Notion database (table View), I'd like to have the number of words/characters/sentence contained in each note.

Here is an example, where I tediously entered the count manually:

[image]

Is there a way to have this count calculated using a formula or anything?

Comment: Please read checkou the Notion Help Center, share what you found and why it didn't meet your needs. Ref [ask]. P.S. Here is the article about formulas 
 -> https://www.notion.so/help/formulas

Comment: @Rubén thanks, I have already read this article but formulas seem to only account for other properties and I could not find anything about accessing the database content. This is the only resource I found that could have been helpful yet, so I can unfortunately not improve my question much.